# I have created a python code to get a simple calculator, but it doesn't show the expected output. Please lend a hand

Tags: python, python-3.x, indentation

I made this code for a simple python calculator and it doesn't give the expected output. Instead this issue occurs: **if(select_op(choice) == "+"): IndentationError: unexpected indent** If someone could please point out the issue in my code and help me with the correct code, that would be grate.
Here is what I have done so far :

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2
def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2
def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2
def power(num1, num2):
    return num1 ** num2
def rem(num1, num2):
    return num1 % num2
def select_op(choice):
    return choice
while True:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Add      : + ")
    print("2.Subtract : - ")
    print("3.Multiply : * ")
    print("4.Divide   : / ")
    print("5.Power    : ^ ")
    print("6.Remainder: % ")
    print("7.Terminate: # ")
    print("8.Reset    : $ ")
    choice = input("Enter choice(+,-,*,/,^,%,#,$): ")
    print(choice)
    if (select_op(choice) == -1):
        print("Done. Terminating")
        exit()
    else:
        num1 = float(input("Enter First Number  : "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number : "))
            if(select_op(choice) == "+"):
                print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1,num2))
            elif(select_op(choice) == "-"):
                print(num1, "-", num2, "=", sub(num1,num2))
            elif(select_op(choice) == "*"):
                print(num1, "*", num2, "=", mul(num1,num2))
            elif(select_op(choice) == "/"):
                print(num1, "/", num2, "=", div(num1,num2))
            elif(select_op(choice) == "^"):
                print(num1, "^", num2, "=", power(num1,num2))
            elif(select_op(choice) == "%"):
                print(num1, "+", num2, "=", rem(num1,num2))
            elif(select_op(choice) == "$"):
                return True
            else:
              print("Something Went Wrong")
```

Comment: Your code is simply mis-indented. Look at where those `if`s start in relation to the `num1`/`num2` lines.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is misindented at the line if(select_op(choice) == "+")
and any further lines. Just remove the tabs. Also, don't use return. You are not in a function. You can use break instead or something like that. Here is a working version:

```
def add(num1, num2):
    return num1 + num2
def sub(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2
def mul(num1, num2):
    return num1 * num2
def div(num1, num2):
    return num1 / num2
def power(num1, num2):
    return num1 ** num2
def rem(num1, num2):
    return num1 % num2
def select_op(choice):
    return choice
while True:
    print("Select operation.")
    print("1.Add      : + ")
    print("2.Subtract : - ")
    print("3.Multiply : * ")
    print("4.Divide   : / ")
    print("5.Power    : ^ ")
    print("6.Remainder: % ")
    print("7.Terminate: # ")
    print("8.Reset    : $ ")
    choice = input("Enter choice(+,-,*,/,^,%,#,$): ")
    print(choice)
    if (select_op(choice) == -1):
        print("Done. Terminating")
        exit()
    else:
        num1 = float(input("Enter First Number  : "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter Second Number : "))
        if(select_op(choice) == "+"):
            print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1,num2))
        elif(select_op(choice) == "-"):
            print(num1, "-", num2, "=", sub(num1,num2))
        elif(select_op(choice) == "*"):
            print(num1, "*", num2, "=", mul(num1,num2))
        elif(select_op(choice) == "/"):
            print(num1, "/", num2, "=", div(num1,num2))
        elif(select_op(choice) == "^"):
            print(num1, "^", num2, "=", power(num1,num2))
        elif(select_op(choice) == "%"):
            print(num1, "+", num2, "=", rem(num1,num2))
        elif(select_op(choice) == "$"):
            break
        else:
            print("Something Went Wrong")
```